# Stuck at GNU GRUB

Tags: boot

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with no other OS alongside.

Normally, when I start the computer, it shows the Asus logo first and then go to the Ubuntu loading screen and finally to Ubuntu home screen.

Now it shows Asus logo first and then shows GNU GRUB purple screen asking me to choose OS (I've already mentioned that Ubuntu is the only one OS I installed in my laptop).

So I choose Ubuntu, hit enter and it goes back to Asus logo and to GNU GRUB screen again.

It happens this way again and again and again, in other word, it's looping.

GNU GRUB version is 2.02 beta2-9

> ```
>                      GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1
> ```
>
> Ubuntu
>
> Advanced options for Ubuntu
>
> Memory test (memtest86+)
>
> Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Above is what the purple screen looks like.

I tried the third option Memory test. Found no error till pass 3.

There are two options in "Advanced options for Ubuntu"

> Ubuntu, with linux 3.13.0-27-generic
>
> Ubuntu, with linux 3.13.0-27-generic (recovery mode)

When I hit them, both options show the black terminal-like screen for a second or two and then to Asus logo. It is also looping.

Some say to fix this problem using boot repair. And some say boot repair slow down the reboot process.

Sorry for long detail question and thank you all...

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem... I assume something can be done in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file but I'm not sure how...
I think the relevant part is in section "menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu" (but it's too long to add as a comment here, it may be found somewhere there: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8078742/)

Comment: Hey Vinze, that problem i was facing was too hard for me to try solving it. So I clean-installed the 14.10 beta version and what I had found out was both 14.04 and 14.10 beta are not as prefect as 13.10. So now i am downloading new released 14.04.1 file. Hope this time everything working fine. Anyway, thank you for your information.

Comment: I found by launching the grub commands one at a time which one had defect and why... Apparently the installation was faulty (premature end of file on the kernel image), by using an other live-usb the installation went right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Ubuntu, with linux 3.13.0-27-generic (recovery mode)` and rebuild the broken packages. Then rebuild GRUB and start Ubuntu again.

Comment: Could you please tell me more detail since I am a new user to Ubuntu. And I am not allowed to open any options including "recovery mode".